# Cannot get "jQuery.inArray" to work in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have created a little interaction that displays list items and when clicked rotates them - http://jsfiddle.net/S79qp/430/

I have recently had to change `.indexOf()` to `jQuery.inArray` because `.indexOf()` does not work in IE8. The problem I have is that I cannot get it working as I am unfamiliar with this method. Can someone show me what I have done wrong

```
       index = jQuery.inArray(a, current) + 1;
   if (index < 0 ||  index >= l.length) {
       index = 0;
   }

   next = (l.eq(index).html());

   jQuery(this).html(next);

  return this;
```

Comment: To get familiar you can read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/.

Comment: That's what I read to get me to where I am. It hasn't helped much @VisioN

Comment: Are you getting the correct index values?

Comment: In the console? @BhumiSinghal

Comment: the code you have provided above is pretty much unclear. What is current ? a? l? So please first check the value of index and see if that is incorrect or if rest of the code is an issue.

Comment: Here is the full fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S79qp/430/. Current is the list item it is currently displaying. @BhumiSinghal

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YsTSS/ is a simple working eg of inArray

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28790/discussion-between-bhumi-singhal-and-milo-j)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in your inArray, the sequence of the parameters sent is incorrect.

It should be

```
 index = jQuery.inArray(current,a) + 1;
```

It is the (value you are looking for) , (where to look into )

http://jsfiddle.net/S79qp/431/ this is the correct fiddle

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it @Bhumi Singhal

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter is the value , and the second is the array you look for .. so you have it backwords

It should be

```
index = jQuery.inArray(current, a) + 1;
```

Quoting [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

> `jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )`
>   **Description:** Search for a specified `value` within an `array` and return its index (*or -1 if not found*).